# using git hook after commit

Tags: git, hook, environment, githooks

I have just started writing a web application.

I am using GIT for version control and I have git and web server in the same computer.

Application has 3 environments: dev, test and production

I want to use git hook after every commit to update dev, test or production application.

what is the best practice for this?

I need something like this:

1. when I commit, dev must automatically be updated
2. when commit message contains "test: " in front of message - dev and test must be updated.
3. when commit message contains "production: " in front of message - production, dev and test must be updated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a suggestion (because it feels more consistent and easier): Use one _branch_ for dev, one for test and one for production. Everytime you push to "test" a hook should update your test env (and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just written a hook / mini bash script to solve this problem

```
#!/bin/bash

if git log --pretty=format:%s -1 | grep -q "^test: "
then
    #action / update dev/test
elif git log --pretty=format:%s -1 | grep -q "^production: "
then
    #action / update dev/test/production
else
    #action / update dev
fi
```

It is my first bash script so.. please help to improve this :)

Comment: Using `git checkout -f` here could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Irakli idea, here is what I have working as a post-receive in my repo...

```
#!/bin/bash

MESSAGE=$(git log -1 HEAD --pretty=format:%s)

if [[ "$MESSAGE" == *\[staging\]* ]];
then
    #action / update staging
    # another method not being used...
    # GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/working/site/ git checkout -q -f staging
    echo "NOTE: Beginning Auto-Push to Staging Server... "
    `git push staging`
    echo "========================================================
======== Done! Pushed to STAGING.com  ============= 
======== Thanks Captain. Keep up the good work! ========
========================================================"
elif [[ "$MESSAGE" == *\[production\]* ]];
then
    #action / update production
    echo "NOTE: Beginning Auto-Push to Production Server... "
    # `git push production`
    echo "========================================================
======== Done!!! Pushed to Production.com  ======= 
======== Test immediately for any errors! =========
========================================================"
fi
```

Note:

to make the 'git push staging' work, you need to have a .git/hooks/post-reveive hook on that working tree. I used [this code](https://github.com/mislav/git-deploy/blob/master/lib/hooks/post-receive.sh) except I added 'umask 002 && git reset --hard' at the bottom.

I also had to add a denyrecive to that working tree's .git/config file:

```
[receive]
    denycurrentbranch = ignore
```

Note 2:

Please note this setup IS NOT for everyone... only for small(ish) sites where quick & dirty updates are fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a post-commit hook which will parse the commit message by using something like `git log -1 --format=%B` and do the appropriate action like `git push dev` etc.

If you are talking about pushing your commits to a remote central repo and that repo has to do this, then you have to use a `post-receive` hook in a similar way. Note that commit hooks run on the client repo where you commit.

With that said, pushing to environments using what you say in the message is not a proper workflow. You can have different branches, where you can cherry pick your commits etc. You can setup hooks such that when you push to `test` branch, the test environment is updated and so on.

Comment: You've helped me but it's not full answer. Please check my new post about this problem. Thanks again!